# In Clojure, how do I sort a set of maps by a key within a value?

Tags: clojure

This is an awkward question to phrase, but say I have a set of maps like so:

```
(def person-1 {:name "Joshua" :birthday {:day 5 :month 12 :year 1960}})
(def person-2 {:name "Louise" :birthday {:day 17 :month 4 :year 1987}})
(def person-3 {:name "Jessica" :birthday {:day 28 :month 5 :year 1972}})

(def people #{person-1 person-2 person-3})
```

How would I sort `people` by their birth month, for example?

I know that I could just do `(sort-by :name people)` if I wanted to sort by name, but I'm not sure, syntactically, how the example above would work.

Comment: Jessica's birth month should be `5`, not `:5`. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(sort-by (comp :year :birthday) people)
```

this sorts on the person's year of birth.

---

`comp` takes a list of functions and composes them into a single function that first takes the parameter, runs the function on the right first, takes the result and then proceeds leftward.

See [`comp` in ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/comp) for details.

Answer (score 1):

sort-by takes a function as it's  first argument, so you can do:

```
(sort-by (fn [m] (-> m :birthday :month)) people)
```

Comment: It's slightly faster than comp due to the macroexpansion over creation of an anonymous class (though not by much)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an anonymous function:

```
(sort-by #(:year (:birthday %)) people)
```

Share and enjoy.